# React.js: Shareable URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, share, react-router

I want to understand my options in terms of enabling shareable URLs to specific pages, and more importantly, specific states on those specific pages. I am thinking that one way to achieve this is to make my components react to the URL path (with or without queries) in order to determing what and how to render.

Therefore I ask:

**Must my react components be dependent on the URL in terms of how to render, if I want to achieve shareable links?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use some sort of client-side router. The main one used by most React apps is react-router. It lets you tie URL changes to UI state, giving you shareable URLs. Check it out:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: This is definitely the step in the right direction. The next task for anybody thinking about this same question would be to learn how to use the router effectively in order to use URL-driven state, etc.